# Indicator icons don't change on theme change

Tags: gnome, icons, battery

I have changed my theme but the battery, messaging and network icons won't change. It shows the regular Gnome icons. How can I change these?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Which theme was that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the icon theme.

The Icon themes are in /usr/share/icons

Each theme has an "index.theme" file and this file will have "Inherits" listed on about the 4th line of the file. It is likely that this icon theme uses the Gnome theme as a default "Inherits" to provide icons not supplied by the theme (missing icons).

One way to change this is to edit the Inherits field in the /usr/share/icons/themename/index.theme file to point to a different (Inherits) theme to fall back on some theme other than Gnome. (Don't forget to change "themename" to the actual name of the theme)

Or, search through the theme folders try to locate the icons you do not like. Delete these icons and replace these icons with the icons of your choice but make sure to name the new icons the same names the old icons had so when you re-load the theme the new icons will automatically load under the given names.

Comment: Hi, I see that there are corresponding icons in the themepack. @mchid

Comment: I tried removing the inherits but it won't work. Is there anyway to associate the icons manually?

Comment: @JyeRamirez yes there is, there are two ways you can do this. You can replace the existing icons in the theme with icons of your choice, giving the new icons the same names as the old ones (easiest) . . . or you can import your own icons into the theme and reference them in the index.theme file (more difficult).

Comment: @JyeRamirez you may want to check out some of the themes at http://www.noobslab.com . Also, http://www.webupd8.org has some ppas as well. If you don't want to install ppas you can usually download and extract icon themes to the /usr/share/icons folder